# Mask a View's Path in It's Superview To Reveal It's SuperSupervView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics

I am trying to figure how to mask the path of a view based on the path of it's subview to reveal the underlying view. I'm not sure that I can articulate what I'm trying to do 100% clearly, so here's a pic I drew:

[image: my beautiful drawing]

To further clarify and drive the point home - View 3 is a subview of view 2. View 2 is a subview of view 1. View 3 has a clear background that reveals View 1.

I want to be able to dynamically mask this area based on the subviews of View 2. So - in view 2's drawRect - I want to be able to survey its subviews, attain their frames, and mask view 2 to those frames.

I'm not too shabby with the rest of iOS/Objective-c, but I'm still leaning Core Graphics and can't quite figure this one out. Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way might be for View 2 to draw all of itself as if there were no subviews, then iterate the subviews calling `NSEraseRect` with each subviews frame.  Do note that view 3 is going to have to be completely transparent (i.e. not draw anything) for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've got some working code here that does what you are attempting to do. Just make sure you set the `backgroundColor` of your UIView to `clearColor`.

Here's the `drawRect:` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor purpleColor] setFill];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        CGContextAddPathWithRect(context, subview.frame, NO);
    }
    CGContextAddPathWithRect(context, rect, YES);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

Essentially, what's happening here is that we create a bunch of paths for the subviews that go **counter-clockwise**, and then we make a single large path going **clockwise** for the current view's frame. Then, because of the even-odd rule, it will only color the part of the view that is not covered by subviews.

I've create this function `CGContextAddPathWithRect` to make the code cleaner and easier to read. Here's its implementation:

```
void CGContextAddPathWithRect(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, BOOL clockwise) {
    CGFloat x, y, width, height;
    x = rect.origin.x; y = rect.origin.y;
    width = rect.size.width; height = rect.size.height;
    if (clockwise) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x + width, y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x + width, y + height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y + height);
    } else {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x + width, y + height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x + width, y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y + height);
    }
    CGContextClosePath(context);
}
```

Here's a zip link to the test project I've created: [SOHoleSubviews.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20180054/Stack%20Overflow/SOHoleSubviews.zip)